# Why rebooted Macbook Pro with Mountain Lion prevents adding or moving files at Desktop?

Tags: macos, desktop

Whenever I reboot my Macbook Pro since installing OSX 10.8 the desktop is locked, prohibiting files from being dropped on or moved from the desktop. I can right-click, select “Get Info” and uncheck the “locked” box, but it will return the locked status the next time the machine sleeps or reboots.

How can I keep the desktop unlocked?

Comment: You may want a more descriptive tile for your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [OS X Recovery Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) has a utility called `resetpassword` which, apart from the obvious, will also reset the permissions for your home holder.

1. Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>cmd ⌘-R</kbd>, and keep holding them until the Apple icon appears.
2. Once started up, from the menu bar at the top, go **Utilities** > **Terminal**
3. Type in `resetpassword` and hit enter, and the Reset Password utility will open.

[image: Reset Password utility]

4. Select the user, change the password, and hit 'Save' to save the password, and then below that hit 'Reset' to fix the permissions